# C# Why can't interfaces implement methods like this? What is a workaround to solve my issue?

Tags: c#, interface, implementation

Why can't interfaces implement methods like this?

```
public interface ITargetableUnit {
        //Returns whether the object of a class that implements this interface is targetable
     bool unitCanBeTargeted(){
        bool targetable = false;
        if(this is Insect){
            targetable = (this as Insect).isFasterThanLight();
        }
        else if(this is FighterJet){
            targetable = !(this as FighterJet).Flying;
        }
        else if(this is Zombie){
            targetable = !(this as Zombie).Invisible;
        }
        return targetable;
    }
}
```

**Insect, and Zombie all already derives from base class Creature, and FighterJet derives from class Machine** However, not all Creature-s are targetable and do not use ITargetableUnit inteface.

Is there any workaround to solve the issue that I am facing?

Comment: Interfaces does not have behavior, what you looking for is abstract class

Comment: Because interfaces don't allow you to provide implementations. Instead make a hierarchy like this, `Creature` -> `TargetableCreature` -> `Insect`/`Ghost`/`Zombie` and `Creature` -> `NonTargetableCreature` -> `WhateverIsntTargetable` however, since your interface has a different implementation for each type, you should just implement the interface in each class.

Comment: You should just have an `ITargetableCreature` and `INonTargetableCreature` then just check for either of those in a main method.

Answer (score 7):

Like everybody said you can't define behaviour for interfaces. Inherite the interface to the specific classes.

```
public interface ITargetableUnit 
{

     bool unitCanBeTargeted();

}

public class Insect : ITargetableUnit //you can add other interfaces here
{

     public bool unitCanBeTarget()
     {
          return isFasterThanLight();
     }
}

public class Ghost : ITargetableUnit 
{
     public bool unitCanBeTarget()
     {
          return !Flying();
     }
}

public class Zombie : ItargetableUnit
{
     public bool unitCanBeTarget()
     {
          return !Invisible();
     }
}
```

Comment: As a nitpick, you don't inherit interfaces in classes, you implement them.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot The correct way of saying it is Interface implementation inheritance.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664593(v=vs.71).aspx. At least I think that way, it is possible to be wrong.

Comment: @mybirthname No, you're misintepreting the title of that page. It refers to how *inheriting* from a class that *implements an interface* means you also implement that interface.

Comment: It is possible I don't want to argue about it, I will agree with you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want an abstract class and not an interface?

Interfaces define what methods a class provides. Abstract classes do this as well but can also take over some calculations for every child.

Please be aware that from a technical perspective an `Insect` can also be a `Zombie`.

Happy coding!

```
public abstract class TargetableUnit
{
    //Returns whether the object of a class that implements this interface is targetable
    public bool unitCanBeTargeted()
    {
        bool targetable = false;
        if (this is Insect)
        {
            targetable = (this as Insect).isFasterThanLight();
        }
        else if (this is FighterJet)
        {
            targetable = !(this as FighterJet).Flying;
        }
        else if (this is Zombie)
        {
            targetable = !(this as Zombie).Invisible;
        }

        return targetable;
    }
}

public class Insect : TargetableUnit
{
    public bool isFasterThanLight()
    {
        return System.DateTime.UtcNow.Second == 0;
    }
}
public class FighterJet : TargetableUnit
{
    public bool Flying { get; set; }
}
public class Zombie : TargetableUnit
{
    public bool Invisible { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Extend you answer. Adding why. Otherwise this should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, you can actually do this (**DONT!**) but this isnt considered a good practice to make extensionmethods for code you have acces to. [Mybirthname's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35244174/1789202) solution is the way to go, this is just for demonstration.

```
public interface ITargetableUnit { }


public static class ITargetableUnitExtension
{

    public static bool unitCanBeTargeted(this ITargetableUnit unit)
    {
        bool targetable = false;
        Insect insect = unit as Insect;
        if(insect != null)
            return insect.isFasterThanLight();
        FighterJet jet = unit as FighterJet;
        if(jet != null)
            return !jet.Flying;
        Zombie zombie = unit as Zombie;
        if(zombie != null)
            return zombie.Invisible;
        return false;
    }
}
```